# Discordjs v13.1 bot not playing sound with mp3 file

Tags: typescript, discord.js

Need some help with my bot playing an mp3 file. My bot joins the voice chat successfully and the play duration is the same length as the file but there is no audio being played. The bot icon does light up green but there is no sound.

Here's the code

```
    await entersState(voiceConn, VoiceConnectionStatus.Ready, 10e3)
    const player = createAudioPlayer()
    player.on('debug', m => {
      console.log(m)
    })
    player.on('error', error => {
      console.error(`Error: ${error}`)
    })

    const resource = createAudioResource(join(__dirname, '../../songs/song.mp3'))

    player.play(resource)
    player.on(AudioPlayerStatus.Playing, () => {
      console.log('Now playing')
    })

    voiceConn.subscribe(player)

    await interaction.followUp('Playing!')
    await entersState(player, AudioPlayerStatus.Idle, 10e3)
    voiceConn.destroy()
```

Here's the log from player

```
from {"status":"idle","resource":false,"stepTimeout":false}
to {"status":"buffering","resource":true,"stepTimeout":false}
Now playing
state change:
from {"status":"buffering","resource":true,"stepTimeout":false}
to {"status":"playing","missedFrames":0,"playbackDuration":0,"resource":true,"stepTimeout":false}
state change:
from {"status":"playing","missedFrames":0,"playbackDuration":8700,"resource":true,"stepTimeout":false}
to {"status":"idle","resource":false,"stepTimeout":false}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using a readable stream as an input for audio resource?

```js
const resource = createAudioResource(fs.createReadStream(join(__dirname, '../../songs/song.mp3')));
```